# SQL Central for Sybase 16 SP 02

Tags: sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere, sybase-ase

ALL,

First time post here in DB Administrators, so please be patient.

In the past long time ago I was working with Sybase SQL Anywhere on Windows. There I got the actual server, ISQL utility, and a little GUI application called SQL Central, which helped managing the database I was working for in the GUI mode.

Couple of days ago, I installed "big" Sybase - version 16 SP02 on Linux. To my surprise I saw only the server itself and the ISQL utility. No SQL Central or an application of that nature. Going thru the docs, I also didn't see anything.

Now my question is: is SQL Central an outdated software? Or maybe it is only supplied with SQL Anywhere? This utility was very helpful and I was even running ISQL from it if I needed to run some queries on the DB

I don't mind just using ISQL but that application was very helpful.

Thank you for any hints you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sybase Central is no longer provided in the new ASE versions. With ASE16 SP02, you can use ASE cockpit instead.

http://help.sap.com/ase1602#section7

Comment: thank you for the info. Does it have the same interface or is it different?

Comment: the interface is different